# Looking for example of reading a file and sending data to Sql using Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, orchestration

I am a newbie to the `Biztalk` world and up to now I am able to read file and send that data to `Sql` and vice-versa using an orchestration and by configuring physical ports in Biztalk Administration, but I want to receive and send data using the `sql-adapter` in a single orchestration, even if its not using single orchestration than also I want the way to do it, and also I want to understand all the `functoids` if any example available.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are in the very beginning stages of learning BizTalk. I would advise you to spend some time learning the basics. There are very good resources listed here

http://biztalk247.com/educate.aspx

http://biztalk247.com/learnmedia.aspx

There is virtual labs sections for various topics..spend a day or two going through all the example.

http://www.cloudcasts.net/ is another resource I'll recommend, where they got lot of small videos help you understand topics.

I'll ignore the advice from Ashish Jaiman, custom adapter development is not a trivial task and its for advanced BizTalk developers

Answer (score 3):

I would start with the links below
1.  http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/adapters-included.aspx 
2.  It is very easy to develop a custom adapter using SDK and Adapter Pack ( you can find more info on the same link on the right side under Adapters)

and also a great resource

http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/reviewers-guide.aspx

Comment: OP should be able to do most tasks using the out of the box `sql` or better still, `wcf-sql` adapters.